# How to fetch Google account contacts after signin with Google in Android application?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve Google contacts after login into my app using Firebase Auth. Initially I am not requesting scope permission to access user contacts later on when I need it I am invoking the scope request.

After getting permission allow from the user I want to fetch google contacts to my app for this I required access token from Google. I am getting it at the time of login if scope permission is granted and after requesting scopes if user allows app to access contacts but it says unauthorized, I don't know why it expires suddenly.

```
private void getAuthToken(GoogleSignInAccount account) throws IOException, GoogleAuthException {//Get current user account google access token
    Scope SCOPE_CONTACTS_READ = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
    Scope SCOPE_EMAIL = new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL);

    if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext()),
            SCOPE_CONTACTS_READ,
            SCOPE_EMAIL)){

        Log.i(TAG," going to get accessToken");
        //Get google Access token in the background
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    String scope = "oauth2:"+ SCOPE_EMAIL+" "+ SCOPE_CONTACTS_READ;

                    Log.i(TAG," accessToken in background task");

                    String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account.getAccount(), scope, new Bundle());
                    Log.d(TAG, "accessToken:"+accessToken);

                    if (accessToken!=null){
                        sharedUtilities.setGoogleAccessToken(accessToken);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```